# Math Saturation Symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm searching for a math symbol that shows saturation. It looks like a slash with a horizontal line at each end.
I found a question about drawing it in a node: [Saturation block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161075/saturation-block)

But I want to use it as a subscript in math mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can design your own symbol without `tikz`. Use `\mathchoice` to allow for use as a subscript or subsubscript.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc} % needed to subtract from \hght

\newlength{\wdth}
\newlength{\hght}
\newlength{\dpth}

\newcommand{\sat}{\mathchoice%
{\settowidth{\wdth}{/}\settoheight{\hght}{/}\settodepth{\dpth}{/}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.25em}{.09ex}\hspace{-.13\wdth}/%
    \hspace{-.15\wdth}\rule[\hght-.09ex]{.25em}{.09ex}}
{\settowidth{\wdth}{/}\settoheight{\hght}{/}\settodepth{\dpth}{/}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.25em}{.09ex}\hspace{-.15\wdth}/%
    \hspace{-.15\wdth}\rule[\hght-.09ex]{.25em}{.09ex}}   
{\settowidth{\wdth}{$\scriptstyle /$}\settoheight{\hght}{$\scriptstyle /$}\settodepth{\dpth}{$\scriptstyle /$}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.2em}{.08ex}\hspace{-.17\wdth}\scriptstyle /%
    \hspace{-.17\wdth}\rule[\hght-.08ex]{.2em}{.08ex}} 
{\settowidth{\wdth}{$\scriptstyle /$}\settoheight{\hght}{$\scriptscriptstyle /$}\settodepth{\dpth}{$\scriptscriptstyle /$}%
    \rule[-\dpth]{.15em}{.07ex}\hspace{-.19\wdth}\scriptscriptstyle /%
    \hspace{-.19\wdth}\rule[\hght-.07ex]{.15em}{.07ex}} 
}

\begin{document}

$A\sat B_{A\sat B_{A\sat B}}$

\end{document}
```

If you want longer or shorter tails you can adjust the lengths in the `\rule` parameters. The `.25em` (or `.2em` for subscript, `.18em` for subsubscript) controls the length.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 5):

First create a `standalone` version of your icon, here in `saturation.tex`:

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter

\pgfdeclareshape{record}{
\inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]
\inheritbackgroundpath[from={rectangle}]
\inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}]
\foreach \x in {center,north east,north west,north,south,south east,south west}{
\inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{\x}
}
\foregroundpath{
\pgfpointdiff{\northeast}{\southwest}
\pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
\northeast
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{0.33\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0}{-0.33\pgf@ya}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.33\pgf@xa}{0}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.33\pgf@xa}{0}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{-0.33\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\southwest}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpoint{-0.33\pgf@xa}{-0.6\pgf@ya}}}
}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[record,minimum size=1cm,fill=blue!30,draw] (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, use this code to include it as the height of the local value of `1ex`, with a little horizontal gap on each side.  This code will adjust to the current font size (so no problem if you go `Huge`) as well as to the current math style (`\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\sat{\ThisStyle{%
  \kern.5\LMpt\includegraphics[height=1\LMex]{saturation}\kern.5\LMpt}}
\begin{document}
\centering
Here is \sat.
In math, $A_{\sat}$
\[
A_{\sat_{\sat}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously, you can change the size by adjusting `1\LMex` to something different.  You can adjust the gap by adjusting the `.5\LMpt` to something different, and you can change the color and line thickness in the original `tikz` code.

For example, by changing the color at `saturation.tex` to `gray!5` and adding a `thick` specification to the draw, one gets this:

[image]

That carries over directly into the main document, where I have changed the height specification to `1.3\LMex`, to arrive at:

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

To help the OP with a follow up request to eliminate the border and axes, replace `saturation.tex` with this:

```
\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (-.5,-.4);
\coordinate (B) at (-.3,-.4);
\coordinate (C) at (+.3,+.4);
\coordinate (D) at (+.5,+.4);
\draw [black, thick] (A)--(B)--(C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then, with the document code definition that

```
\newcommand\sat{\ThisStyle{%
  \kern.5\LMpt\includegraphics[height=1.3\LMex]{saturation}\kern.5\LMpt}}
```

we arrive at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel,graphicx}
\newcommand\sat{\ThisStyle{%
  \kern.5\LMpt\includegraphics[height=1.3\LMex]{saturation}\kern.5\LMpt}}
\begin{document}
\centering
Here is \sat.
In math, $A_{\sat}$
\[
A_{\sat_{\sat}}
\]
\Huge
\[
A_{\sat_{\sat}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is awesome. This is almost what I was looking for, except that I don't need the frame and the axes. Only the diagonal line with the two horizontal lines. I don't have much experience with tikz, what do I need to change for that? Is there really no math symbol for that?

Comment: @Kaniee See my supplement code.

Answer (score 3):

With `picture` mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\saturation}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern1mu\nonscript\mkern-1mu
    \mathpalette\satur@tion\relax
    \mkern1mu\nonscript\mkern-1mu
  }%
}

\newcommand{\satur@tion}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1|$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \saturation@linethickness{#1}%
    \begin{picture}(0.6,1)
    \roundcap
    \polyline(0,0)(0.2,0)(0.4,1)(0.6,1)
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
\newcommand{\saturation@linethickness}[1]{%
  \linethickness{%
    1.25\fontdimen8
      \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
      \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
  }%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\saturation B_{A\saturation B_{A\saturation B}}$

\end{document}
```

The command `\saturation@linethickess` is an old trick of mine, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412159/4427

[image]

I chose to make the symbol the same vertical size as `|`; the width is 60% of the height and the three parts have equal width. Feel free to change the proportions. You can get it wider with

```
\newcommand{\satur@tion}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1|$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}%
    \saturation@linethickness{#1}%
    \begin{picture}(0.8,1)
    \roundcap
    \polyline(0,0)(0.2,0)(0.6,1)(0.8,1)
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
```

[image]