# What is a good survey of solutions/workarounds for 'LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.'?

Tags: fonts, symbols

We all know the dreaded error message `LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.`

Is there an up to date survey of why it's there, and what can be done about it?

For example, I know that macros such as `\DeclareSymbolFont` gobble up some limited capacity of internally allocated counter, dating back to some magic numbers Knuth chose at the time for TeX.

I also know that newer systems (LuaTeX, XeTeX) have a higher capacity, but not for, e.g., `\DeclareSymbolFont`.

There are also all kinds of tricks one can do to limit the number of font families a standard package (like bbm) loads, and so on.

Is there a source that summarises the problem and solutions/workarounds comprehensively?

If there is more than one, what is the most recent/up-to-date?

## Context

I often need to extract only one (or a small number) of symbols from a font. The general advice seems to be to look up that package's sourcecode and extract the bare minimum. For example, to get the `\boxright` symbols from the boisik font, we could use these four lines:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bskma}{\skewchar\font130 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bskma}{m}{n}{<->bskma10}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{bskadd} {U} {bskma}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxright} {\mathbin}{bskadd} {"A0}
```

The problem is that if I need to this more than a handful of times, I will start getting a `Latex Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.`.

## Partial solution

@David-carlisle 's solution below is attractive in this context, but I'm still not quite getting it to work. The basic definition is something like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\NewFontImport[6]{
\newcommand#1{\begingroup\mathchoice%
  {\hbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\tf@size}  \usefont{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}\char#6}}%
  {\hbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\tf@size}  \usefont{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}\char#6}}%
  {\hbox{\fontsize{\sf@size}{\sf@size}  \usefont{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}\char#6}}%
  {\hbox{\fontsize{\ssf@size}{\ssf@size}\usefont{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}\char#6}}%
  \endgroup
}}
\makeatother
```

This works well for, e.g., boisik `\boxright`:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bskma}{\skewchar\font130 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bskma}{m}{n}{<->bskma10}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\NewFontImport\boxright{U}{bskma}{m}{n}{"A0}
```

(Well, it doesn't because boisik currently has a bug with its sans serif Greek Sigma that only appears at scale `mag:=0+420/600`. I sent a bug report to the author. Commenting out sans serif Greek Sigma in the metafont sources works around it.)

## Outstanding problems

But it doesn't seem to work across the board.

1. It doesn't work for `mathabx` big-operators:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10>
      <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88>
      mathx10
      }{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\NewFontImport\bigboxright{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{"D9}
```

as the `\bigboxright` ends up being typeset below the baseline. I think I'm passing the wrong argument to `\setfont`, but not sure what I should pass.

2. It doesn't work for delimiters:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{}
\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{
  <-6>  MnSymbolE5
  <6-7>  MnSymbolE6
  <7-8>  MnSymbolE7
  <8-9>  MnSymbolE8
  <9-10> MnSymbolE9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE10
  <12->   MnSymbolE12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{b}{n}{
  <-6>  MnSymbolE-Bold5
  <6-7>  MnSymbolE-Bold6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolE-Bold7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolE-Bold8
   <9-10> MnSymbolE-Bold9
  <10-12> MnSymbolE-Bold10
  <12->   MnSymbolE-Bold12}{}
\NewFontImport{\lsemsym}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{'102}
\NewFontImport{\rsemsym}{OMX}{MnSymbolE}{m}{n}{'107}
```

I can use `\lsemsym` and `\rsemsym` on their own, but I cannot use `\open\lsemsym \sum_{i=1}^n a_n \close\rsemsym` as they are typeset inside a textbox, and not as variable sized delimiters.
(Lots of kudos for @David Carlisle for all his patience in getting me this far!)

Comment: in classic tex there is only one workaround, load less fonts, so it is rather document specific. Especially if you are using unicode math where a single font can hold thousands of characters rather than just 256, the restriction to 16 symbol fonts isn't that much of a problem normally although there you do have the theoretical possibility of using `\Umathchardef` rather than `\mathchardef` so going beyond 16.

Comment: Thanks, a 'there is no solution in TeX' is also a good answer, though of course not comprehensive to the other systems. 

That said, if I want to mix symbols from different fonts, then unicode access to a single font doesn't help either, unless I create my own custom fonts.

Comment: you don't need a survey and nothing can be done in a system calling itself tex, there is simply a hard limit of at most  16 math fonts in any math expression.

Comment: note you can have any number of fonts loaded in the document in different math versions so it is only an issue if you need more than 16 fonts in a single formula, and even there you can do the same as \boldsymbol which basically means `\hbox\mathversion{somethingelse}$math with different fonts$}`

Comment: as always the question would be improved if it had a test file that would show the problem and could be used to test answers

Comment: If the usage was limited to a small number of symbols for a given font, you could use `standalone` to create the symbol as a PDF.  Then you could import it as an image and use `scalerel` package to give it the right math sizing characteristics, as in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477182/math-saturation-symbol/477186#477186

Comment: You might try the etex package.  IIRC, it extends all limitations of 256 to 32K.

Comment: Thanks John, but @DavidCarlisle said in a comment, the 16 symbol fonts is impossible to get around directly

Comment: @JohnKormylo no:-) (etex.sty does nothing useful in a post 2015 latex, and in any case this restriction is 16 not 256

Answer (score 4):

The restriction is only to 16 fonts within a single math expression, it is rather rare to need more than that.  In luatex or xetex you can use `\Umathchardef` rather than `\mathchardef` to access beyond 16 families if you really need that, or even in classic TeX you can avoid the issue in the same way as `\boldsymbol` avoids the issue, switch to an hbox then set up a different font regime just for the single character then return to the outer formula.

This is a single math expression set with pdflatex with 24 different Z

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$
Z                                       %  0
\mathrm{Z}                              %  1
\mathit{Z}                              %  2
\mathsf{Z}                              %  3
\mathbf{Z}                              %  4
\mathfrak{Z}                            %  5
\mathcal{Z}                             %  6
\mathbb{Z}                              %  7
\mathtt{Z}                              %  8
\hbox{\usefont{OML}{txmi}{m}{it}Z}      %  9
\hbox{\usefont{OML}{txmi}{bx}{it} Z}    % 10
\hbox{\usefont{OT1}{txr}{m}{n} Z}       % 11
\hbox{\usefont{OT1}{txr}{bx}{n} Z}      % 12
\hbox{\usefont{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n} Z}     % 13
\hbox{\usefont{LS1}{stix2}{m}{it} Z}    % 14
\hbox{\usefont{LS1}{stix2}{b}{n} Z}     % 15
\hbox{\usefont{LS2}{stix2}{b}{it} Z}    % 16
\hbox{\usefont{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n} Z}     % 17
\hbox{\usefont{LS2}{stix2}{m}{it} Z}    % 18
\hbox{\usefont{LS2}{stix2}{b}{n} Z}     % 19
\hbox{\usefont{LS2}{stix2}{b}{it} Z}    % 20
\hbox{\usefont{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n} Z} % 21
\hbox{\usefont{LS1}{stix2frak}{b}{n} Z} % 22
\hbox{\usefont{LS2}{stix2cal}{m}{n} Z}  % 23
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you include a `\selectfont` if the definition of `\usefont` includes ones already?

Comment: @OhadKammar because it is a relic of an earlier version, I'll clean up:-)

Comment: OK, thanks, this is progress towards something I've been long after, though it doesn't quite answer the original question.
Re. what I'm after, some issues with this code: (1) the hbox code doesn't preserve the current math mode (can be worked around). (2) I don't quite see how to import arbitrary math characters from a package, e.g., with what to replace the `\DeclareMathSymbol{\mac}{1}{fontname}{"69}` I might see in a font `.sty` file.

Comment: @OhadKammar you can extract the equivalent `\usefont` or modify the packages math setup to be in a custom mathversion instead of the default one then use `\hbox{\mathversion{zz}$\mac$}` why do you need this? I don't think I have ever needed this in a real document

Comment: I promise I'm working on a real document :).
I'm just trying to extract different single symbols from different packages. This seems to always require setting up a `\DeclareMathSymbol` for said font, which causes the above error. Your solution is promising, but I don't see how to access the specific character from each package to make it work.

Comment: I think the right term is 'slot': how do I use a specific slot in a given font.

Comment: @OhadKammar as I said in a comment under the question, if you had provided an example document could make an answer that referenced that.

Comment: @OhadKammar but replacing `Z` by `\char"68`  will make it use slot hex 68.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105619/discussion-between-ohad-kammar-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: using `\char"68` doesn't work. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @OhadKammar it would work if you used it as in this answer, you have set up the command to use a text mode `\usefont` which is consistent with thi sanswer but then you used it in math mode.

Comment: Ah, I see --- thanks! But then I'm not sure how to make it match the current mathmode (as in the code in the question).

Comment: Sorry for my probably trivial question: is a "math expression" any sequence enclosed by a pair of $, `\[ \]` or `\( \)`? Thank you.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas yes or other math environments such as `align`

Answer (score 1):

I can explain the "*outstanding problem #1*".

The `\bigboxright` symbol is declared in `mathabx` as

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bigboxright}     {1}{mathx}{"D9}
```

Note that it has category `1`, and so it is *operator*. TeX has special function for displaying operators (see `make_op` in the Knuth's `tex.web` file). In particular, it can switch to a larger version of the symbol in display mode and shift the symbol vertically if necessary. To emulate this behaviour, I suggest the following modification of the code:

```
\newcommand\makeopNewFont[6]{
  \setbox0\hbox{\fontsize{#1}{#1}\usefont{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}\char#6}%
  \lower\dimexpr .5\ht0-.5\dp0-\fontdimen22\textfont2\copy0
}
\newcommand\NewFontImportOp[7]{
  \newcommand#1{%
    \mathop{\mathchoice%
        {\makeopNewFont{\tf@size}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#7}}%
        {\makeopNewFont{\tf@size}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
        {\makeopNewFont{\sf@size}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
        {\makeopNewFont{\ssf@size}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}}%
    }%
  }%
}
%....
\NewFontImportOp\bigboxright{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{"D9}{"F9}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know an easy way to determine the code corresponding to the paired (a larger) symbol (`"F9` in this case), because of this pairing is stored inside of the font (so-called `charlist` entries). To found `"F9`, I've analyzed `\tracingoutput`-generated log of a test page with original `\bigboxright` command. Alternative way is to look at all glyphs using the `fonttable` package and found a match there.

Most likely it is possible to emulate most of other math categories as well (by just prepending `\hbox` with `\mathbin`, `\mathrel`, etc. to get correct kerning):

```
\newcommand\NewFontImport[7]{%
  \newcommand#1{%
    #5{\mathchoice%
        {\hbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\tf@size}\usefont{#2}{#6}{#3}{#4}\char#7}}%
        {\hbox{\fontsize{\tf@size}{\tf@size}\usefont{#2}{#6}{#3}{#4}\char#7}}%
        {\hbox{\fontsize{\sf@size}{\sf@size}\usefont{#2}{#6}{#3}{#4}\char#7}}%
        {\hbox{\fontsize{\ssf@size}{\ssf@size}\usefont{#2}{#6}{#3}{#4}\char#7}}%
    }%
  }%
}

% Note: I've changed the order of arguments to match \DeclareMathSymbol
\NewFontImport\times{U}{m}{n}{\mathbin}{matha}{"02}
```

But emulation of delimiters is too much complicated (because of construction of left/right delimiters of arbitrary size). It's where I give up.